# Get data frame columns and its value as variables in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I am fetching data from `mysql` table using `pyspark` like below.

```
df = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "{}:{}/{}".format(domain,port,mysqldb)).option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable", "(select ifnull(max(id),0) as maxval, ifnull(min(id),0) as minval, ifnull(min(test_time),'1900-01-01 00:00:00') as mintime, ifnull(max(test_time),'1900-01-01 00:00:00') as maxtime FROM `{}`) as `{}`".format(table, table)).option("user", "{}".format(mysql_user)).option("password", "{}".format(password)).load()
```

The result of `df.show()` is below

```
+------+------+-------------------+-------------------+
|maxval|minval|            mintime|            maxtime|
+------+------+-------------------+-------------------+
|  1721|     1|2017-03-09 22:15:49|2017-12-14 05:17:04|
+------+------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Now I want to get column and its value seperately.

I want to get

```
max_valval = 1721
min_valval = 1
min_timetime = 2017-03-09 22:15:49
max_timetime = 2017-12-14 05:17:04
```

I have done like below.

```
 max_val = df.select('maxval').collect()[0].asDict()['maxval']
 min_val = df.select('minval').collect()[0].asDict()['minval']
 max_time = df.select('maxtime').collect()[0].asDict()['maxtime']
 min_time = df.select('mintime').collect()[0].asDict()['mintime']
```

Is there a better way to do this in `pyspark`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you are using `collect` 4 times which is cost effective. You can try some python skills to do this. I have one approach which you can try:-

```
df = (sqlContext.read.format("jdbc")
    .option("url", "{}:{}/{}".format(domain,port,mysqldb))
    .option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
    .option("dbtable", """(
        select ifnull(max(id),0) as maxval, ifnull(min(id),0) as minval, 
               ifnull(min(test_time),'1900-01-01 00:00:00') as mintime, 
               ifnull(max(test_time), '1900-01-01 00:00:00') as maxtime 
         FROM `{}`) as `{}`""".format(table, table))
    .option("user", "{}".format(mysql_user))
    .option("password", "{}".format(password)).load())


for key, value in df.first().asDict().items():
    globals()[key] = value

print minval
print maxval
print mintime
print maxtime
```

In this way you can convert columns to variable. In case you need further assistance, let me know.

Comment: I am getting the following error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack`

Comment: @Question_bank just a small mistake I forget to add `items` after  `.asDict().items()`. I modified answer you can check now.

Comment: @RakeshKumar What if df.show() has more than one result?

Comment: @AlexRajKaliamoorthy in this case it’s like 2-Dimensional array.